# How to convert an Image.file() object to a Image file in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am displaying an Image with filter effects on Screen using in filter

Image.file(
imageFile,
color: color.withOpacity(0.5),
colorBlendMode: BlendMode.hardLight,
),

I need to write these color effects to 'imagefile'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Image.file();` is a widget, if you need to write widget to a disk as an image.
Take a look at this [Creating raw image from Widget or Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957086/creating-raw-image-from-widget-or-canvas)

otherwise, if you need to edit an image(like adding a filter)
maybe it works
[How To Create A Filtered Image In Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305968/how-to-create-a-filtered-image-in-flutter)

or below package
https://pub.dev/packages/photofilters

Comment: i want to save image with this effect

Comment: Image.file( imageFile, color: color.withOpacity(0.5), colorBlendMode: BlendMode.hardLight, ),

Comment: maybe it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62046676/flutter-save-blendmode-to-image